# StreamEnabled table property causes Serverless failure

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm using Serverless to deploy my AWS cloudformation stack. On one of my tables, I enable streams via "StreamEnabled": true. When this is enabled, I get an error on deployment: `Encountered unsupported property StreamEnabled`.

If I remove the property, I get a validation exception: `ValidationException: Stream StreamEnabled was null`.

I found a git issue that was addressed and apparently fixed ([here](https://github.com/99xt/serverless-dynamodb-local/issues/100)), but after upgrading to v1.3, I'm still getting the same errors on deployment.

Can anyone lend insight as to what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1):

It is enabled by default. You can check it from shell:

```
aws dynamodbstreams list-streams
{
    "Streams": [
        {
            "TableName": "MyTableName-dev", 
            "StreamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:0000000000000:table/MyTableName-dev/stream/2018-10-26T15:06:25.995", 
            "StreamLabel": "2018-10-26T15:06:25.995"
        }
    ]
}
```

And:

```
aws dynamodbstreams describe-stream --stream-arn "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:00000000000:table/MyTableName-dev/stream/2018-10-26T15:06:25.995"
{
    "StreamDescription": {
        "StreamLabel": "2018-10-26T15:06:25.995", 
        "StreamStatus": "ENABLED", 
        "TableName": "MyTableName-dev", 
        "Shards": [
            {
                "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000000-0000000f", 
                "SequenceNumberRange": {
                    "StartingSequenceNumber": "00000000000000000000000"
                }
            }
        ], 
        "CreationRequestDateTime": 1540566385.987, 
        "StreamArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:0000000000000000:table/MyTableName-dev/stream/2018-10-26T15:06:25.995", 
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "KeyType": "HASH", 
                "AttributeName": "application_id"
            }
        ], 
        "StreamViewType": "KEYS_ONLY"
    }
}
```

It is not a solution, but found that fact I realized that I don't have an issue.

Comment: I think the streams are not enabled by default